# Как блокировать iframe на конкретном сайте?

Tags: iframe

Буквально сегодня столкнулся с проблемой блокировки iframe, т.к. ни один из ад блокеров на chrome.google.com/webstore/ не смог заблокировать рекламу во фрейме, а гугл начал тупить. Самым простым решением было "javascript always block on this site", есть ли более мягкие варианты? На этих сайтах адбокеры бессильны kp.ua, korrespondent.net

Answer (score 1):

Опций много.

1. Самая "брутальная" и быстрая версия. С помощью хрома и вкладки network смотрим, куда идет запрос с фрейма.  С помощью commandline и команды nslookup находим все айпишники домена. Затем идем в файл hosts и отправляем их все на 127.0.0.1 (бан по айпишникам в том числе забанит и https соединение, в отличие от бана по домену)
2. Более хитрый но и более сложный вариант. Ставим себе Greasemonkey, и пишем свой скрипт который будет вырезать желаемый фрейм по селектору и с задержкой/повторами.
3. Ну и как вариант, идем на форум адблока, документируем фрейм, ждем решения.

Comment: Спасибо! Получается я всё правильно сделал, просто заблокировал js, пусть админы голову ломают почему среди посетителей рост хостов с отключенным js